# List view button without standard controller

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce, dynamic-apex, dynamic-vf-component

Is it possible to create a list view button without a standard controller?
My requirement is, I want to create a List view button for any object. In the current scenario, I have to write the same logic for multiple objects.

for example :

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="Account" extensions="BulkSMSController" recordSetVar="Member">
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="Contact" extensions="BulkSMSController" recordSetVar="Member">
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="Custome_Object" extensions="BulkSMSController" recordSetVar="Member">
```

Is it possible to write dynamic standard controller?

Answer (score 3):

No. The best you can do is move the core markup you want to not duplicate into a `Visualforce Component` instead. You need one top level `Visualforce Page` for each object you wish to support, end of story.